# How can I get MStest to return a non-zero exit code when failing?

Tags: mstest, .net-core, exit-code

I am trying to test some .NET Core code with MSTest, and I am discovering that the test suite returns an exit code of zero even when there are failing tests. I am able to reproduce the problem using the code samples from [the blog post announcing the technology](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/). The code to reproduce the problem is [on github](https://github.com/johnnymo87/exit-code-problems), and the important parts are reprinted below.

`project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "testRunner": "mstest",

  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.0.1-preview",
    "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.0-preview"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`ExitCodeTests.cs`

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace SampleNetCoreUnitTests
{
  [TestClass]
  public class TestClass
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodPassing()
    {
      Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodFailing()
    {
      Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the tests with `dotnet test && echo THIS SHOULD NOT BE ECHOED`, I get the following output:

```
Discovering Tests ...
Executing Tests ...
Passed   TestMethodPassing
Failed   TestMethodFailing
Error Message:
   Assert.IsTrue failed.
Stack Trace:
   at SampleNetCoreUnitTests.TestClass.TestMethodFailing() in /app/ExitCodeTests.cs:line 17
============ Test Run Summary ============
Total tests: 2. Passed: 1. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0
Test Run Failed.
SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 1, Failed: 0.
THIS SHOULD NOT BE ECHOED
```

Even though I have a failing test, the test suite is returning an exit code of zero, and thus echo command is being executed.

Short of switching to an alternative such as xUnit, how do I get my test suite to return a non-zero exit code when failing?

**Edit:** [The author of this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391046/2197402) seems to believe MSTest should return a zero exit code even when failing. Maybe it's a MSTest "feature". Maybe I should consider some alternative test runners.

Comment: Just to close the loop, I'll comment here and say that I solved my problem by switching to xUnit.

Comment: I hope some sane man in MS will get back on this during next half a year or so )

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed, and a updated on NuGet here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-test-mstest/1.1.1-preview